# reset extension file userdefualt from another class

Tags: swift, extension-methods, reset, ibaction, userdefaults

Reset count userdefualt to from a function outside of the extension method. In this case its func easy. Right now the code starts at 0 and only goes unless i can use a func to stop the code from going up.

```
extension UIViewController {
func updateVisitCount() {
    let key = String(describing: type(of: self))
    let count = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) as? Int ?? 0
    UserDefaults.standard.set(count + 1, forKey: key)
}}

 class easy: UIViewController {
@IBAction func delete() {
//reset let count to 0
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one more function thats it

```
extension UIViewController {
   func updateVisitCount() {
     let key = String(describing: type(of: self))
     let count = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) as? Int ?? 0
     UserDefaults.standard.set(count + 1, forKey: key)
   }
   func clearVisitCount() {
     let key = String(describing: type(of: self))
     UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: key)
   }
}

class easy: UIViewController {
   @IBAction func delete() {
  //reset let count to 0
   self.clearVisitCount()
  }
}
```